# Problems understanding Ruby code

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
all_backups = dir.entries[2..-1].sort.reverse
max_backups = 20
unwanted_backups = all_backups[max_backups..-1] || []
```

I think it gets all entries in a defined folder. What is `[2..-1]`? What is `all_backups[max_backups..-1] || []`?

Comment: Read about ranges: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html

Comment: @Felix I'm sorry, but can you please clarify what you mean with your comment on @R_O_R's answer? By last 20, do you mean, the last 20 entries of `all_backups` or of `unwanted_backups`? And may I know what do you mean by oldest? Can you please tell where the oldest entries be located? (by way of array index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir.entries[2..-1]
```

get elements from index 2(means 3rd element of your array) to last index(last element of your array). In Ruby `-1` means last element of the `Array` instance.

```
all_backups[max_backups..-1] || []
```

`all_backups[max_backups..-1]` gives `nil`, then assign with an empty array `[]` to the variables other wise returned array from `all_backups[max_backups..-1]`.

Comment: thanks. What I want to do: I make mysql dumps from a database and I want to save the last 20 backups. But with the code above 20 backups were saved, when the 21 is going to save all 20 backups will be deleted .. The oldest one should be deleted ...